# How to Hash MD5 an entire table in sql server 2012

Tags: md5-file

I Need to create a Hash MD5 for every table my ssis script creates in a database.
Is it possible? if so can anyone please share some code, i have Searched and Searched and not getting anywhere

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you mean by creating hash for every table. If you mean you need to create hashes for table names, you can use the below query in your database for SQL Server:

`SELECT name, HASHBYTES('MD5', name) FROM sys.tables`

Comment: Ok so we have created a table per file, the table is one column width and has a string value in each row (75k records per file), i now have to concatenate all these rows in this table (already tried coalesce - too slow), then calculate a MD5 Hash on that consolidated String. The Operation does not change the structure of the file at all. The Result of the MD5 then gets appended to the table in a new row with other bits of info.